# Qual o significado de "migo", "tigo', "sigo", "nosco" e "vosco"?

Tags: pronomes, pronomes-reflexivos

Enquanto pesquisando no Priberam:

[image: descrição do significado de "migo" pelo Priberam]

[image: descrição do significado de "tigo" pelo Priberam]

[image: descrição do significado de "sigo" pelo Priberam]

[image: descrição do significado de "nosco"]

[image: descrição do significado de "vosco"]

Antes, gostaria de dizer que serão múltiplas perguntas e que será um texto longo. Eu gostaria de fazer uma pergunta para cada palavra, mas apenas ficaria pior. Desculpa pelo tamanho.

### Migo

Pela descrição do Priberam, é uma forma antiga e basicamente diz "flexão do pronome *mim*, quando precedida da preposição *com*", então, "com migo" = "comigo". Esta não me deixa dúvidas.

### Tigo

Diz o Priberam que é uma flexão do pronome *tu* "hoje, **só empregada em contigo**". Onde mais a se utilizava? Isso seria uma das flexões do pronome *tu* vinda do latim que, pelo português ter perdido os casos, só serve com "com"? Imagino que sim.

### Sigo

Diz a descrição "O mesmo que **consigo**", ok, e "Forma nominativa do pronome *se* (em consigo)". O que é a forma nominativa? É possível a usar sem "com"?

### Nosco

É dito "Forma do pronome *nós*, **geralmente precedida da preposição *com***". Novamente, isso há relação com "O mesmo que **conosco**"?

### Vosco

O meu favorito e mais importante para mim. Primeiramente, o que é forma comitativa? "Comitativa" tem relação com "com"?

Segundamente, "Plural: voscos |ô|", o que significa "voscos", então? Qual a diferença entre "vosco" e "voscos"?

O último, mas menos importante: por que, para mim, é mais natural dizer "para vosco" do que "para vós"? Isso também ocorre a outrem? Isso também ocorre um pouco com "conosco" ao invés de "nós", mas não vejo problema nenhum em falar "isso é para nós". Porém, não há nenhuma naturalidade para mim, em dizer "para vós" — soa-me errado; "para vosco" soa-me muito mais correto.

Obrigado por teres lido este texto longo. Desculpa pela longura desse texto; espero que não tenhas dormido, enquanto o lendo.

A quem quiser responder, a última pergunta não precisa ser respondida e podes responder apenas uma parte, porém, por favor, inclui as perguntas relacionadas a "vosco", podendo ignorar a última.

A quem quiser editar, podes tirar "migo", se quiseres.

Comment: Até o século XVII ou XVIII, era comum as pessoas utilizarem os termos *com migo*, *com tigo*, *com nosco* e *com vosco*. Quanto à dúvida "para vosco", é difícil para nós sabermos o porquê isso é mais natural para você. A propósito, pesquisei e encontrei apenas uma referência ao termo "para vosco".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Migo, tigo*, etc. são palavras do português medieval que significavam simplesmente *comigo, contigo*, etc. (como já diz o Artefacto), tendo sido substituídas por estas últimas no português moderno. Tudo o mais são confusões do Priberam. As formas medievais vêm do latim *mēcum, tēcum*, etc., com os mesmos significados, como se mostra na tabela abaixo.

---

**Latim**          **Português medieval**           **Português moderno**

[mēcum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mecum)                       migo                               comigo

[tēcum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tecum)                         tigo                                  contigo

[sēcum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secum)                        sigo                                consigo

[nōbīscum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nobiscum)                   nosco                             conosco

[vōbīscum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vobiscum#Latin)                   vosco                             convosco

Fonte: Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa

---

As palavras latinas já incluíam a preposição *cum*, ’com’. Por exemplo, [*tēcum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tecum) vem de *te*, ablativo de *tu*, + *cum*. A posição de *cum* após o pronome é curiosa. É um bocado como se nós disséssemos *mim com, ti com, nós com*, etc. Cícero disse que tudo começou com [*nōbīscum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nobiscum) ([*nōbīs*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nos#Latin) é o ablativo de *nōs*, ’nós’) para evitar  *cumnobis*, um cacófato muito feio porque soaria como *cunnō bīs* (pormenores no [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nobiscum)). Linguistas modernos sugerem que *cum* tivesse originalmente sido um advérbio, tendo por isso posição mais livre na frase.

A passagem de *-cum* a *-go* (*mecum → migo*, etc.) pode parecer estranha, mas a terminação *-m* perdeu-se ainda no latim vulgar, e o *-c-* intervocálico tendeu a passar a *-g-* na evolução para o português (como em *amicum → amigo, formicam → formiga, posticum → postigo, lacum → lago*). O dicionário Houaiss explica o resto em grande pormenor no caso de *comigo* (desenvolvo as abreviações):

> **comigo** […] ETIMOLOGIA *com* + antigo *migo*, este do latim *mēcum*, de *mē* ablativo do pronome pessoal *ego* + *-cum* ’com’; como se vê, ocorreu um uso pleonástico de *cum* ou *com* na posição prepositiva, devido ao apagamento da noção do *cum*, aglutinado pospositivamente sob a forma *-go*; é possível que tal uso pleonástico tenha ocorrido no latim vulgar **cumecum*, devido ao facto de ocorrer também em espanhol *comigo* , no italiano antigo *commeco* e no velhoto *konmaik*; a passagem -e->-i- deveu-se à influência da forma tónica *mim*; ver *lhe*; formas históricas s[éculo]XIII *comigo*, sXIII *comego*, sXIII *conmigo*, sXIV *cõmjgo*, sXV *commiguo*

Encontras explicações análogas, mas mais resumidas, nos verbetes *contigo, consigo, conosco* e *convosco*. Esta adição do *com-* ás formas medievais faz-me lembrar o *atrás* em coisas do tipo *há cinco anos atrás*, muito comum em Portugal. Pergunto-me se os educadores antigos também acusaram *comigo, contigo*, etc. de serem vícios de linguagem.

Podes ver no Glosario da Poesía Medieval Profana Galego-Portuguesa muitos exemplos de uso de [*migo*](http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/2206), [*tigo*](http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/3323), [*sigo*](http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/3178), [*nosco*](http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/2364), [*vosco*](http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/3673). Podes encontrar ainda mais exemplos, com contexto completo, no [Corpo Informatizado do Português Medieval](https://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt//).

Quando é que as formas medievais caíram em desuso, eu não sei dizer. Mas procurei nalgumas obras, e já não as encontras n’*Os Lusíadas* (1572), nem na *Crónica de D. João I* (1443) de Fernão Lopes, nem no *Leal Conselheiro* do rei D. Duarte (1391-1438); são só as formas modernas as que encontras nestas obras.

### Lapsos e idiossincrasias do Priberam

As tuas restantes dúvidas resultam de lapsos e falta de uniformidade por parte do Priberam.

*Migo, tigo*, etc. sem *com* significavam o mesmo que *comigo, contigo*, etc. O Priberam dizer isto acerca de [*sigo*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/sigo) e [*nosco*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/nosco) mas não de [*migo*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/migo), [*tigo*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/tigo) e [*vosco*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/vosco) é simplesmente um falta de uniformidade na apresentação.

Precedidas de *com*, *migo, tigo*, etc. podem ser reinterpretados como as formas dos pronomes pessoais no caso comitativo, que é o caso “que exprime companhia” (Houaiss). Isto aplica-se a todas as pessoas — *migo, tigo, sigo, nosco* e *vosco*. O Priberam mencioná-lo apenas no caso de [*vosco*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/vosco) é novamente uma falta de uniformidade; e dizer que [*sigo*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/sigo) é a forma nominativa só pode ser engano.

Dizer que [*migo*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/migo) é flexão de *mim* e que [*tigo*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/tigo) é flexão de *tu* é novamente falta de uniformidade. *Eu, me, mim* são tudo flexões do mesmo pronome pessoal. Seria mais natural dizer que *migo* é flexão de *eu*, pois normalmente usamos como referência o caso reto.

Também só pode ser engano o Priberam dizer que [*vosco*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/vosco) é um nome masculino, ou que admite plural *voscos*.

### *Para vosco*

Já houve além de ti pelo menos duas pessoas que escreveram na internet *para vosco*, [aqui (2017)](https://www.facebook.com/Helustre-boy-amor-com-letras-110795946236604/) e [aqui (2019)](https://www.netflu.com.br/buscamos-investir-pouco-avisa-pedro-abad-sobre-reforcos-para-2019/). Nenhum dos casos é exemplo de boa escrita. Outros resultados são enganos do Google, que leu mal *vosso* ou *Vasco*. Diz-se e sempre se disse *para vós* e não **para vosco*. *Para vós* soa-te mal possivelmente porque o tratamento por *vós* caiu em desuso há muito tempo (sobrevive em alguns falantes no norte de Portugal e na linguagem da igreja) e tu não estarás familiarizado com ele.

Comment: Acerca de "para vosco", concordo; é que eu acho legal a conjugação e a pronúncia -- principalmente os ditongos -- de "vós", então, eu estou tentando falar "vós" em vez de "vocês". Eu acho esquisito o Priberam ter erros assim, já que é um dicionário famoso e extremamente usado. Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @Schilive, pois o Priberam é muito popular entre o pessoal aqui do site; nunca compreendi bem porquê. O Aulete e o Michelis, também disponíveis online, têm normalmente explicações mais desenvolvidas. Encontrei *sigo* no século XV,  "Meraugis tragia **sigo** a carta u sa nacença era escripta" ('trazia consigo a carta onde sua...') na *Demanda do Santo Graal* (histórias do Rei Artur) [CIPM](https://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt//). Mas encontras só duas ocorrências de *sigo*, e 27 de *consigo*.

Answer (score 3):

*Migo*, *tigo*, e por aí em diante significam *comigo*, *contigo*, ...

> Dom Meendo, vós veestes
> falar **migo** noutro dia;

([Cantigas de Escárnio e Maldizer](https://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/corpus/texto.jsp?t=d&id=18868))

> Muito foi noss' amigo
> Gabriel, quando disse:
> "Maria, Deus é **tigo**."

([Cantigas de Santa Maria](https://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/corpus/texto.jsp?t=d&id=21472))

> Polo meu mal filhou [s’ ora] el rei
> de mar a mar, assi Deus mi perdon,
> ca levou **sigo** o meu coraçon

([Cantigas de Amigo](https://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/corpus/texto.jsp?t=d&id=22875))

> Nem estas armas eu nunca lhas vi
> trager na guerra; destes sinaes
> que ora trage, nom trouxe taes
> **nosco** na guerra, quand’el-Rei foi i;

([Cantigas de Escárnio e Maldizer](https://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/corpus/texto.jsp?t=d&id=18948))

> Chegades [vós, ai] amiga, du e´ meu amigo
> e con el falastes, mais eu ben vos digo
> que falarei **vosco** tod’ aqueste dia,
> pois falastes con quen eu falar queria

([Cantigas de Amigo](https://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/corpus/texto.jsp?t=d&id=18948)]

Já nestes textos do séc XIII aparece por vezes a preposição *con*. A origem das formas *comigo* etc. é portanto [pleonástica](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-do-pronome-comigo/30010).

Quanto ao dicionário indicar um plural *voscos*, parece-me simplesmente um lapso.

Comment: Desculpa pelo -1. Eu queria dar +1, mas apertei errado e não é mais corrigível.

Comment: É possível remover um *downvote* após edição da resposta/pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

### Tigo

Acredito que o redator desta página do dicionário se enganou, pois em um momento ele toma o caso reto como origem da flexão, já em outro ele toma o caso oblíquo.

Em algumas pesquisas, foi possível encontrar que "tigo" é/era uma forma abreviada de falar a palavra "contigo". Isso pode ser evidenciado em [Cantigas de Escárnio e Maldizer](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/corpus/texto.jsp?t=d&id=19017). No entanto, em outras pesquisas mais concretas, informa-se que "tigo" é, na verdade, a forma original da palavra derivada do latim "tecum".

### Sigo

Em poucas palavras, "forma nominativa" é o mesmo que "caso nominativo" e que, por sua vez, pode substituir o conhecido "caso reto".¹²

Sim, a palavra **sigo** pode ser utilizado como conjugação do verbo **seguir**. Exemplo:

> Eu sigo você, vá adiante.

No entanto, com o mesmo sentido de **consigo**, não encontrei esse modo de utilização na lingua portuguesa e, portanto, posso supor que não existe.

### Nosco

Do mesmo modo que o sigo, não encontrei fontes confiáveis da utilização do **nosco** sem a precedência do **com**. Portanto, é possível supor que não existe.

### Vosco

A forma comitativa, também conhecida como **caso** comitativo³, é um caso gramatical que, sim, tem total relação com o “com”. Este caso indica companhia e as únicas palavras declinadas dele que ainda estão em uso na lingua portuguesa são as que você citou (comigo, contigo, conosco, consigo e convosco).

Seriamente recomendo que você busque outros dicionários, pois este possui diversos erros, já que "vosco", do mesmo modo que "vós", já representa o plural.

Eu não vejo naturalidade alguma em utilizar o "para vosco" ou "para nosco", que estão incorretos. Na verdade, vejo um modo de querermos deixar uma palavra mais formal e apresentável. De modo simples, posso citar os verbos **ter** e **possuir**. Muitos utilizam o possuir para deixar o verbo ter de um modo mais formal. No entanto, ambos os verbos possuem diferenças e, portanto, é errôneo utilizá-los com o mesmo sentido.

¹ [Arquivo da Universidade de São Paulo](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/311732/mod_resource/content/1/Complementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o.pdf).
(pesquise por "caso reto (nominativo)" no arquivo).

² [Wikipedia - Caso nominativo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_nominativo).

³ [Wikipedia - Caso comitativo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_comitativo).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110654/discussion-on-answer-by-chanp-qual-o-significado-de-migo-tigo-sigo-nos).